# Handling different types of a component from other components

Tags: reactjs

I have two components: `A` and `B` in a `React` app. Both of them access component `C` which can be of 6 different types (type is passed through `props` object). Right now I am defining 4 types inside `A` and 2 types in `B` just as strings. I do not like that the types of `C` are now spread across `A` and `B`. What could be done architecturally according to best practices to avoid such a situation? I heard that `Redux` may help, however, I can not rewrite the whole app from scratch and from what I read about `Redux`, it seems that it would be needed. I would prefer all of the types of a component to be somewhere near that component, so that it could be looked up easily.

Comment: If you using ts then you can declare an interface and let the component know which 2 types B will get and which 4 types A will get

Comment: I am already using javascript. You mean side by side start using ts?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit fuzzy what a "type" is and how they are different. Without further information I can only guess that it could make sense to break component C down into multiple other components, probably using the same core. Then A/B would not only pass props to magically change C but directly implement different versions of C (and potentially pass on props if still needed).

Buttons are a good example for this. There you have various variations of buttons, but all of them have pretty much the same logic how to handle clicks etc.

```
const TYPES = {
  PRIMARY: 'primary',
  WARNING: 'warning',
  DANGER: 'danger',
  SUCCESS: 'success',
}

const BaseButton = ({ 
  text, 
  onClick, 
  buttonType,
}) => (
  <button
    type={type}
    onClick={onClick}
    classnames=(styles[ buttonType ], styles.button) 
    >
    {text}
  </button>
);
export const Primary = props => (
  <BaseButton { ...props } buttonType={TYPES.PRIMARY} />
);
export const Warning = props => (
  <BaseButton { ...props } buttonType={TYPES.WARNING} />
);
export const Danger = props => (
  <BaseButton { ...props } buttonType={TYPES.DANGER} />
);
export const Success = props => (
  <BaseButton { ...props } buttonType={TYPES.SUCCESS} />
);
```

What you also can see here is the use of const TYPES: An object that defines the different types of elements available. This constants, implemented in components and probably exported, can additionally be used to give the different options a location, where they can be looked up.

**What about redux?**

Multiple components influencing each other based on a state is indeed a situation where you might want to consider redux. However if it is only this very limited case redux would not only be an overkill but it would also create a weird structure if you use it just in this single place.